Faster or more pythonic way to populate n by n matrix?
I have a working loop but due to the size of data involved, it's slow and so wondering if there's a better/faster method that I could use instead.
My use case consists of two data frames:
Dataframe A is intended to summarize Dataframe B which is a catalog of data that is not unique.

Dataframe A:

Has been structured to have the unique IDs of dataframe B as its index and the universe of Product_IDs in dataframe B as its columns. Size is 8000 rows x 30 columns (there are 29 different Product_IDs)



ID
20001
20002
...
20030




60001000
6





60001001

27




....






60001999
4


1


....






60008999










Dataframe B:

Is a 20,000 line long 3-column file consisting of values for ID, Product_ID and Quantity. It looks similar to this:



ID
Product_ID
Quantity




60001000
20001
5


60001000
20001
1


60001001
20002
20


60001001
20002
7


60001999
20030
1


60001999
20001
4







The approach I've used is to iterate through the entire 8000x30 matrix and sum the Quantities, but this is slow so wondering if there's another method that's better?
Loop I'm using at present time:
    for i in a_df.index:
        for j in a_df.columns:
              a_df.at[i,j] = b_df.loc[ (b_df['ID'] == i) & (b_df['Product_ID'] == j) ]['Quantity'].sum()


Try: dfB.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Product_ID', values='Quantity', aggfunc='sum')

Thank you this did the trick and is lightning fast comparatively!
